# Adding a string to pointer to pointer in c is not showing anything when accessed

Tags: c

i have been trying c for a while now but i can not handle pointer arrays.
for example

```
char *word;
char *container[100];
```

In the below for loop i am appending single characters of in string to temp then i want to add to *container[100] if the delimiter **.**  is appeared.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    int z = 0;
    int k=0;
    char *word;
    char *container[100];
    char *in = " First Word . Second Word";
    for(k=0; k<strlen(in); k++)  
    {  
        //using . as a delimiter
        if(in[k]=='.')
        {
            container[z] = word;
            printf("%s\n", container[z]); //<---- this prints okey inside loop 
            z++;
            memset(word,0,strlen(word));
        }
        else
        {
            //appending characters to temp, using some method
            snprintf(word + strlen(word), (sizeof word) - strlen(word), "%c", in[k]);
        }
    }
//doesnt print anything outside the loop
printf("Does it print: %s\n", container[0]);
printf("Doest it print: %s\n", container[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

when i try to print the words in container it doesnt show anything:

```
printf("%s\n", container[0]);
printf("%s\n", container[1]);
```

i think i have to do some sort of Dynamic Allocation. But i dont know how.

Comment: Please, post a [mcve]

Comment: explain your code better, what's temp? container[z] ???

Comment: Did you copy it wrong? `What is `container[z]` supposed to do?

Comment: @terencehill; @Barmar Done... is that okey now? Thank you

Comment: Actually not, Complete and Verifiable means that I can copy it into a file, compile and run it and it will show the same error that you are reporting. I can still see this  `container[z]` which is not an istruction.

Comment: @terencehill soo sorry for my noobness. Fixed it now. Ty

Comment: @MichaelWalz fixed. Thanks alot

Comment: @HasnainAli the variable `word` is never initialized. But there are many more problems. Please show us also what output you expect. You mention `temp` in your question but there is no `temp` in your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz but i am appending character to the word, and when i print the container[i] it prints out correctly  inside the loop, but after i do memset, it doesnt print anything outside the loop.

Comment: @HasnainAli you are using an uninitialized variable, therefore you get undefined behaviour. Google "c undefined behaviour". **And please edit your question and show us the output you expect**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer `word` is not initialized before you start using it. This causes undefined behaviour. If you are lucky you get a segmentation fault so you are made aware of the problem and can fix it. If you are unlucky it kinda works but gives weird side effects, like mysteriously overwriting other variables.

Also, `sizeof word` returns the pointer size and not the size of the (allocated) memory area it points to.

The problems with `word` can be fixed by making it an array:

```
char word[100];
```

Now `word` contains 100 bytes of memory that we can safely write to, and `sizeof word` will evaluate to `100`.

The next problem is when you assign the `container` pointers to point to `word`. This will **not** make a copy of the string contained in `word`. Later when you overwrite the contents of word, the contents of `container[i]` will also be overwritten since it points *to the same memory location*. You can use `strdup` to create a dynamically allocated copy:

```
container[z] = strdup(word);
```

Note: `strdup()` is a POSIX function and not part of the C specification. On platforms that don't have `strdup()` you can use `malloc`+`strcpy` to perform the same task.

Comment: yayy, that fixed it... i knew it was because of memory location but was not sure about it. Thanks alot for clarifying this concept for me. :)